# Private certificates from my Azure subscription not shown in new appservice

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up SSL for our new Azure app service.  We have several other app services but they're in a different resource group and under a different app service plan.

On all my previous app services, there is a section on the SSL blade that shows Private Certificates.  And there's an informational block in that section that states "Private certificates list includes all valid private certificates from your subscription."  This text shows on all app services, even the new one.  However, on previously created app services I see my wildcard cert (i.e., *.domainname.com).  On this newly created app service (and new app service plan) I do not see any certs.

We only have the one Azure subscription.  So if the private certificates list includes all valid private certs from our subscription, why doesn't the new one show them?  Is there something I have to do with a new app service and/or app service plan (and maybe resource group as I segregated this into a new one) to make these certs from our subscription appear?

Thanks in advance for any advice you have, 
Denise

Answer (score 0):

Azure said that the cert needs to be imported for each resource group.